# What's the best way to append new type object into boost.hana::tuple?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ TMP. I new to add newly created types into a global boost.hana::tuple object one by one. Something like this:

```
auto animals = boost::hana::make_tuple();

struct Fish { std::string name; };
using animals = boost::hana::append(animals, Fish);

struct Cat  { std::string name; };
using animals = boost::hana::append(animals, Cat);

static_assert(animals == boost::hana::make_tuple(Fish, Cat), "");
```

Basically, what I want at the end is an `animals` with multiple animal types. However, I don't know in advance how many types. With more and more code (header files) being added, the list of `animals` grows. I want each header file should just add its own animal type into the `animals`. Different header files do not know what other header files are doing. They all know the global `animals` list though.

How can I achieve this?